# Pik path on a windows machine doesn't work because of space character

Tags: windows, ubuntu, git-bash, pik

I'm trying to set up pik on my windows machine. In the .pikrc file, there's these lines of code:

```
pik_path=/c/Program files/pik

function pik  {
  $pik_path/pik_runner.exe pik.sh $@
  [[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh
}
```

Apparently, the git bash can't deal with the space between Program and files.

How can I resolve this?

When starting git:

```
sh.exe": files/pik: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with

```
#!/bin/sh
pik_path="/c/Program Files/pik"

function pik  {
  "$pik_path/pik_runner.exe" pik.sh $@
  [[ -s "$USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh" ]] && source "$USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh"
}
```